# JS - Allow div to scroll to end of content, then stop. Other content to remain scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The thing I'm trying to set up is basically a web page split into two columns, left and right, one div each. The left div will be static content, but it will typically be longer/taller than the browser viewport. The right column may be of any length as it will contain blog posts.

When the visitor scrolls the page down, I want both sides to scroll in the normal manner. I want the left side to stop scrolling and remain static when it reaches the end of its content. When the person scrolls up again, the left side should return to normal and scroll up in tandem with the right.

I've also registered at jsfiddle to set up a sort of demo of what I'm after: https://jsfiddle.net/robaxx/c359rbc4/

ok.. so apparently I have to insert the code into the post here using a different but seemingly identical tool to jsfiddle. So I've done that as well.

In any case. I got the JS from other posts on stackoverflow and modified it to suit my html and css demo.

The demo starts with both panels positioned next to each other. after scrolling down a certain amount specified in the script, the left div is set to position fixed and bottom zero.

This is basically the right idea, but is not very slick as the height just a number of pixels rather than the height of the viewport.

So I'm looking for a better version of this. If the left panel can operate smoothly or even be animated or bounced, then even better!

Thanks for any advice on this.
Regards
Rob

edit:
I've changed the fixed height to try and pick up the window.innerheight, which seems like the right idea, but I'm unsure of the syntax and how it fits together so it may be wrong. Any help is appreciated.

edit again:
I've just realised I should be picking up the length of the left div, not the window height. Not sure how to do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var windw = this;
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: 'inherit',
                bottom: 0
            });
        } else {
            $this.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                bottom: 'inherit'
            });
        }
    });
};

$('#left').followTo(windowHeight);

});
```

```css
#left {
  background:lightgrey;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:20px;
  width:25%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

#right {
  background:lightblue;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:20px;
  width:75%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="left">
<p>This side should only scroll down as far as it has content and then become fixed to the bottom.</p><br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br /><br />
<p>Scrolling up should return it to normal behaviour.</p>
</div>

<div id="right">
<p>This side should be able to scroll all the way to the bottom.</p><br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
Lorem ipsum etc etc<br />
</div>
```

Comment: Each container with its own scroll it's not an option for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gerard. I tried various option using divs and css alone and also the old iframes to create scrollable panels, but then I lose the joint scrolling, and worse, I have to then try and deal with the browser scrollbars in both panels. The ideal will be exactly like the demo here, but modified in some way that reads the viewport height and switches to fixed positioning once that amount has been scrolled.